# In Python, how to append text from Arduino in a GtkTextview when connecting to a port?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino, gtk, gtk3

I am using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports

import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class SerialComm(Gtk.Window):

glade = "serial_comm.glade"

builder = Gtk.Builder.new_from_file(glade)
builder.add_from_file(glade)

comboPorts = builder.get_object("comboPorts")
comboBauds = builder.get_object("comboBauds")
btn_conectar = builder.get_object("btnConectar")

textbuffer = builder.get_object("textbuffer")
textview = builder.get_object("textview")

def get_ports(self):
    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())

    for p in ports:
        self.comboPorts.append_text(p[0])
        self.comboPorts.set_active(1)
        print(p[0])
```

**try open a port and get arduino data**

```
def open_port(self, widget):
    port = self.comboPorts.get_active_text()
    baud = self.comboBauds.get_active_text()
    arduino = serial.Serial(port, baud)
    temp = arduino.readline()

    self.textbuffer.set_text(temp)
    self.textview.set_buffer(self.textbuffer)
    arduino.close()

def __init__(self):
    window = self.builder.get_object("window")
    window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

    self.btn_conectar.connect("clicked", self.open_port)

    self.get_ports()

    window.show_all()

if __name__ == '__main__':
application = SerialComm()
Gtk.main()
```

But I have to click on a button to get the data (temperature of a sensor, read every second).

```
self.btn_open.connect("clicked", self.openport)
```

How to update textview content automatically, after clicking the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to open the port and read from it as the information comes in. Example:

```
from gi.repository import GLib #include this import with the rest of your imports

def open_port(self, widget):
    port = self.comboPorts.get_active_text()
    baud = self.comboBauds.get_active_text()
    self.textview.set_buffer(self.textbuffer)
    arduino = serial.Serial(port, baud)
    GLib.timeout_add_seconds(1, self.read_info, arduino)

def read_info (self, arduino)
    temp = arduino.readline()    
    self.textbuffer.set_text(temp)
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks @theGtknerd, worked well. The only problem is that the application does not respond sometimes. thank you so much. maybe I need to use Threads?

Comment: No, threads are not necessary. In a lot of cases threads are a pain. The problem is you are using `readline()` which blocks the program main loop.

Comment: I have a program almost identical to what you are doing. It works really well for me. If you are interested, I will post the code on GitHub.

Comment: your example, I believe, would be very useful for learning. thank you @theGtknerd

Answer (score 0):

Solution from @theGtknerd isn't really ideal. By using `g_timeout_add_seconds` isn't great, you're adding 1 second of latency on data reception. Using `g_timeout_add` would only hide the real problem: you're doing polling.

Instead, [`g_io_add_watch`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-IO-Channels.html#g-io-add-watch) should be used to call a callback when data really arrives. However, this would require having a `GIOChannel` that can be used by `pyserial`. The `GIOChannel` can be created from on a file descriptor, I just don't see how to get the file descriptor from a pyserial object, but that should be doable...